# Assign a column of a data.frame with string name in R

Tags: string, r, assign

I am trying to assign data to an existing dataframe with a name generated in a loop.  A basic example might be

```
A = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b=c(3,6,2))

for (i in 1:2){
    name = paste("Name",i, sep="")
    assign(name, c(6,3,2))
}
```

Now I just need to figure out how to add name1 and name2 to the data.frame A, while keeping their assigned name. I'm sure there is an easy answer, I'm just not seeing it right now.

in the end I would like to end up with

```
A
#a b name1 name2
#1 3 6      6
#2 6 3      3
#3 2 2      2
```

But I need to do this in an automated fashion.

For instance if the for loop could be adapted to be like

```
for (i in 1:2){
    name = paste("Name",i, sep="")
    assign(name, c(6,3,2)
    A= cbind(A, get(paste(name,i,sep="")))  # works but doesn't maintain the column name as name1 or name2 etc
}
```

this however doesn't maintain column names

Comment: This is very confusing what you're asking for.  Could you post what you expect the output to look like?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The other answers are good, but if you are set on using a loop like you have, then this would work:

```
A <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(3,6,2))

for (i in 1:2){
    A[paste("Name", i, sep="")] <- c(6,3,2)
}
```

which gives

```
> A
  a b Name1 Name2
1 1 3     6     6
2 2 6     3     3
3 3 2     2     2
```

Alternatively, `paste("Name", i, sep="")` could be replaced with `paste0("Name", i)`

Comment: That helps a lot. Yes. `A` could not be empty before `for loop`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want this:

```
R> A <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,6,2))
R> colnames(A) <- paste("Names", 1:ncol(A), sep="")
R> A
  Names1 Names2
1      1      3
2      2      6
3      3      2
R>
```

but as Tyler said in the comment, it is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for responding I just clarified what I was looking for.

Comment: Just assign four columns at the beginning, and then the names when/where/how you want them.  My answer already shows you `colnames(A)`, you can also just assign to `colnames(A)[3:4]` or any other valid expression.

Answer (score 3):

Still not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish:

```
A = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b=c(3,6,2))
B <- data.frame(A, c(6, 3, 2), c(6, 3, 2))
names(B)[3:4] <- paste0("name", 1:2)
B
```

Which yields:

```
  a b name1 name2
1 1 3     6     6
2 2 6     3     3
3 3 2     2     2
```